# Drawing ribbon graphs in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am writing some notes about ribbon categories and ribbon graphs and I would need to reproduce some diagrams like the ones on the figures.

Does anyone know an efficient way to do it ? I have no idea so I would have to learn from scratch.

Maybe an external software allowing me to export images would also be a good idea.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suggest to use mathcha editor https://www.mathcha.io/editor

Comment: Hi and welcome to [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)! Have you looked into any solutions yourself so far? Did you find anything or run into issues? Please [edit] your question to include things you've tried (and got stuck), it makes it much easier for others to provide you with a suitable answer.

Comment: Have you looked at the [knots package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/spath3)?